# Liferay dxp 7.3: how to add third party jars for global sharing?

Tags: jar, portlet, liferay-7

how can add 3rd party jars for global sharing?

in 6.1, it just need to add those jar files into tomcat's lib/ext folder. but after upgrade to 7.3, those jars seems not loading and cannot reference in portlets.

please help!

thx.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay 7 replaced its whole foundation and switched to OSGi -- you'll need to provide your third-party jars in an OSGi bundle.

(This basically was the answer. Any elaboration would be too much for this site or would need a more specific question. As Liferays documentation is always in flux, search for "liferay include third-party jars in module" for more info. At the time of writing, [this link](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028710272-Resolving-Third-Party-Library-Package-Dependencies) is a relevant search result.)